# Locking per value with separate locks guarantee

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I would like to have some mechanism that will allow me to acquire lock per  object according to `equals()` implementation.

I was looking for existing solution. I've found **Guava Stripped**, but problem with it is that I don't have guarantee that for different `equals()` value I will get different locks.

In my scenario it is a problem because I need to acquire two locks, the second one while I'm still holding the first one so using the same lock for different values could lead me to deadlock.

Is there any existing solution for what I'd like to achieve? Implementing this on my own can be quite tricky so this is why I was thinking about some existing and tested solution.

EDIT:
As questions arose I'd try to explain a little bit more. I have some kind of transaction in which I update state of two objects. Once I'm starting this transaction I don't want any other thread to start any transaction involving any of those two objects until I finished the already started transaction. However I would like it to be possible to start any other transaction that involves other objects. Example:

Objects: **A**, **A'** (same `equals()` value as **A**, different instance), **B**, **C**

**Thread 1**: trying to acquire lock on **A** and **B**

**Thread 2**: trying to acquire lock on **A'** and **C**

Expected result: if **Thread 1** started transaction, **Thread 2** needs to wait until **Thread 1** finished it's transaction (because **A** and **A'** has the same `equals()` value).

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. You want to get the object lock? Then just synchronize on it.

Comment: @Ben It seems OP wants to use different locks to lock different variables using **synchronised** is actually using a single *lock* `this`.

Comment: @Hearen that's exactly why I asked. Because it's quite unclear to me what they exactly want to do. Maybe an example would help or some formatting on the text.

Comment: Could you please share more details about why you need different locks?

Comment: Some code would aleays help

Comment: I've updated the post with example. I'm just looking for some food for thought. Maybe java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock isn't good idea at all in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly using `equals`, but `equals` and `hashCode` (you should be overriding them together anyway), what's wrong with the following?

```
class LockFactory<T>
{
    private final Map<T, Object> objectToLock = new HashMap<>();

    synchronized Object getLock(T input)
    {
        objectToLock.putIfAbsent(input, new Object());
        return objectToLock.get(input);
    }
}
```

You can synchronize on the `Object`, or return some kind of [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) if you prefer.

Comment: This map size can quickly rise if number of different possible keys is huge. I was wondering whether there is some existing implementation that could handle such nuisances.

Comment: @slakomy So add a method to remove from the map when you're done. If you require `n` locks, you require `n` objects. There's no way around that.

Comment: Removing could be an option but it's also not so straighforward when multiple threads wants to acquire the same Lock. Anyway, thanks for suggestions. I'm just looking for some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have implemented after some thought and suggestions from @Michael. Maybe someone will find it useful or find some errors in it:

```
public class LockedExecutionProvider {
    private final HashMap<Long, LockWithUsageCount> locks = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T executeLocked(Supplier<T> supplier, Long... ids) {
        List<Lock> idsLocks = asList(ids).stream().sorted().map(this::getLock).collect(Collectors.toList());
        idsLocks.forEach(Lock::lock);
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } finally {
            idsLocks.forEach(Lock::unlock);
            asList(ids).forEach(this::returnLock);
        }
    }

    private synchronized Lock getLock(Long id) {
        LockWithUsageCount lockWithUsageCount = locks.computeIfAbsent(id, i -> new LockWithUsageCount());
        lockWithUsageCount.incrementUsageCount();
        return lockWithUsageCount.getLock();
    }

    private synchronized void returnLock(Long id) {
        LockWithUsageCount lockWithUsageCount = locks.get(id);
        if (0 == lockWithUsageCount.decrementUsageCount()) {
            locks.remove(id);
        }
    }

    private static final class LockWithUsageCount {
        private final Lock lock;
        private int usageCount;

        LockWithUsageCount() {
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
            usageCount = 0;
        }

        Lock getLock() {
            return lock;
        }

        void incrementUsageCount() {
            usageCount++;
        }

        int decrementUsageCount() {
            return --usageCount;
        }
    }
}
```